# JPA 2.1 Integration issue with Liberty Profile 16.0.0.4

Tags: hibernate, websphere, websphere-liberty, stax, jpa-2.1

I am trying to integrate my application which running in Liberty Profile 16.0.0.4 but I'm having problems with JPA 2.1.

I use Hibernate 5.1.0.Final entity manager (to use JPA 2.1 features), which does not seem to be working by WLP 16.0.0.4. I have tried Class loader setting as "Parent Last" but no effect. Below is the error for your reference.

Below is the error returned when trying to create the EntityManager .

> CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application . The
>   exception message was:
>   com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException:
>   javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory could not be instantiated:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory:
>   Provider com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLEventFactoryImpl not found.

Appreciate your help on this regard.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an Oracle JRE with liberty, try to add this to the jvm.options file of liberty:

`-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventFactoryImpl`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the IBM implementation of the `stax-api` is likely missing or incompatible.

Comment: i have excluded all the stax-api jar references from my pom.xml